# How to use Conda (base) environment in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, environment

I can add Conda environments using

> pycharm/preferences/project/Project Interpreter

Which is explained in https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/ about how to use your conda environments in pycharm.

But I can't find the option for choosing the base environment,

which I understand is the default environment  all the packages are installed in.

[Here's what it looks like,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86lzr.png) I can choose other environments but not (base).

How can I solve this? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is there `python.exe` in Anaconda folder? Try to scroll a little further

Comment: @user2235698 Yes,there is. So if I select 'python.exe' as interepreter can I use all default packages in conda ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not recommended since Anaconda has many packages and this may slow down your work with PyCharm, consider to create conda environment with packages that you are going to use, see https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html